# Having Trouble Pulling Data From Firebase RT Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uikit

Super new to coding so apologies if something is super obvious here.

I'm working on an app that I can use to keep track of my weight lifting split. I write the data like this:

```
public func writeNewExercise(splitName: String, day: Int, exerciseNum: Int, exerciseName: String, sets: String, repsSecs: String, isTimed: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let user = AuthManager.shared.user
        var exerciseRef: DatabaseReference!
        exerciseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "\(user.uid)/splits/\(splitName)/day \(day)/exercise \(exerciseNum)")
        
        var dataDictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
        dataDictionary["Exercise Name"] = exerciseName
        dataDictionary["Sets"] = sets
        dataDictionary["Reps or Secs"] = repsSecs
        dataDictionary["Is Timed"] = isTimed
        
        exerciseRef.setValue(dataDictionary) { error, _ in
            if error == nil {
                completion(true)
                return
            } else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

This gives me a JSON dictionary in Firebase that looks like this:

```
{
  "8aIzPgurRLPPEYDpXWv54r5JjvH3" : {
    "splits" : {
      "Test Split" : {
        "day 1" : {
          "exercise 0" : {
            "Exercise Name" : "Curls",
            "Is Timed" : false,
            "Reps or Secs" : "12",
            "Sets" : "4"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

What I want to do now is to pull this data so I can insert each exercise into a tableView cell. Don't want to do anything fancy with it -- just be able to view it so I can follow my split. I'm doing this more for practice than practicality. I've tried pulling the data about 15 different ways, and no matter what I do it just won't work. I'm totally stumped. Here is the code I have right now:

```
    public func downloadPost(splitName: String, day: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
        
        let user = AuthManager.shared.user
        var exerciseRef: DatabaseReference!
        exerciseRef = Database.database().reference()
        
        var exerciseArray = [Exercise]()
        
        exerciseRef.child("Users").child(user.uid).child("splits").child(splitName).child("day \(day)").observe(.value) { snapshot in
            
            if snapshot.exists(){
                for x in 0...100{
                
                let nameValue = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "exercise \(x)/Exercise Name").value
                let setsValue = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "exercise \(x)/Sets").value
                let repsOrSecsValue = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "exercise \(x)//Sets/Reps or Secs").value
                let isTimedValue = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "exercise \(x)/Sets/Is Timed").value
                
                let exercise = Exercise(name: "\(nameValue!)",
                                        sets: "\(setsValue!)",
                                        repsOrSecs: "\(repsOrSecsValue!)",
                                        isTimed: isTimedValue as? Bool ?? false)
                    print(exercise.name)
                    print(exercise.sets)
                    print(exercise.repsOrSecs)
                    print(exercise.isTimed)
                exerciseArray.append(exercise)
                completion(true)
                return
            }
        } else {
            print("no snapshot exists")
        }
        
        print(exerciseArray)
        
    }
    }
```

Exercise is a custom class I've created that has a name, amount of sets, amount of reps, and a Bool "isTimed". This code prints:

no snapshot exists, []

Trying other things, I've got it to print something like:

null,
0,
0,
false

Some other stuff I've tried has been:

- using slash navigation instead of chaining .childs in the .observe.value
- using .getData instead of .observe
- throwing DispatchQueue.main.async all over the place
- making the exerciseRef be the whole database, then calling to the specific point when assigning the snapshot.value
- Much else

I've probably put something like 15 hours into just this at this point, and I really cannot figure it out. Any help would be massively appreciated. I'll watch this post closely and post any info that I may have left out if it's needed.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Got everything working by using the code provided by Medo below. For others trying to do something like this, after pulling the array as Medo demonstrated, just set all the labels in your tableViewCell to ExportedArray[indexPath.row].theClassPropertyYouWant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
public func downloadPost(splitName: String, day: Int, completion: @escaping (([Exercise]) -> ())){
    
    let user = AuthManager.shared.user
    var exerciseRef: DatabaseReference!
    exerciseRef = Database.database().reference()
    
    var exerciseArray = [Exercise]()
    
    exerciseRef.child(user.uid).child("splits").child(splitName).child("day \(day)").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        
        guard let exercises = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
            print("Error: No snapshot")
            return
        }
        
        
        
        for exercise in exercises {
            let exerciseData = exercise.value as? [String:Any]
            
            let exerciseName = exerciseData["Exercise Name"] as? String
            let isTimed = exerciseData["Is Timed"] as? Bool
            let repsOrSecs = exerciseData["Reps or Secs"] as? String
            let sets = exerciseData["Sets"] as? String
            
            let exerciseIndex = Exercise(name: "\(exerciseName)",
                                    sets: "\(sets)",
                                    repsOrSecs: "\(repsOrSecs)",
                                    isTimed: isTimed)
            
            exerciseArray.append(exerciseIndex)
            
        }
      completion(exerciseArray)  
    }
}
```

You can call the function `downloadPost` and extract the array from it like this:

```
downloadPost(splitName: "", day: 0, completion: {
    aNewArray in
    
    // aNewArray is your extracted array [Exercise]
    print("\(aNewArray)")
    
})
```

Few things to be aware of:

1. If you want to ensure that your storing your exercises in order (and extract the data in order) then instead of having exercises 0, 1, 2... (in your database), name it by an id called "childByAutoId". Firebase will auto order them for you as you add/push or extract that data. Replace your `writeNewExercise` function with:

   ```
   let user = AuthManager.shared.user
   var exerciseRef: DatabaseReference!
   let key = Database.database().reference().childByAutoId().key ?? ""
   exerciseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "\(user.uid)/splits/\(splitName)/day \(day)/\(key)")

   var dataDictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
   dataDictionary["Exercise Name"] = exerciseName
   dataDictionary["Sets"] = sets
   dataDictionary["Reps or Secs"] = repsSecs
   dataDictionary["Is Timed"] = isTimed

   exerciseRef.setValue(dataDictionary) { error, _ in
       if error == nil {
           completion(true)
           return
       } else {
           completion(false)
           return
       }

   }
   ```
2. Firebase Realtime Database is a breadth first search and download. So you should probably flatten out your database structure as much as possible. This means observing on `exerciseRef.child("Users").child(user.uid).child("splits").child(splitName).child("day \(day)")` would still download all the exercise days.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've been trying to integrate this into my code and I'm still having some trouble. First, I tried adding a return value of [Exercise] and then calling let aNewArray = downloadPost. That returned an empty array. Then, I tried simply creating an array outside of the function, having the function fill it, and then using it, and I still got an empty array. How would you get the array out of this function? I tried adding several print functions to the end of the for...in loop for debugging, and they never seemed to run, so it seems that that for...in isn't getting called

Comment: I modified the downloadPost function to return the Exercise array. I also added the code for how to call downloadPost and extract the array from it. If the for loop never got called then you should check that children are not nil and the snapshot exists.

Comment: You need to make sure that all the children nodes exist when you read from the database. It seems that you don't have a child("Users") node. You should write your data like this in "writeNewExercise"

Database.database().reference(withPath: "Users/\(user.uid)/splits/\(splitName)/day \(day)/\(key)").setValue...

Comment: That must be it! I removed the "Users" path from my write function because I thought it was redundant but never from the download function. I am busy the rest of the night but tomorrow I will get this all up and running then accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Got it all working! I know the comments are just meant for technical questions but I just wanna say I really appreciate you taking the time to help a complete stranger. This was frustrating me to no end and I was beginning to think I should just give up on coding all together. Thanks again!

Comment: Any time Nick :)